# How to disable Option+F14 keyboard shortcut that, by default, opens the Displays System Settings?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878482/what-do-the-parameter-values-in-applesymbolichotkeys-plist-dict-represent but haven't been able to find descriptions of the action ids, at least not one that includes what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to map <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F14</kbd> in `iTerm2` but macOS 13.5 has that bound to open the Displays System Settings.

[image]

How do I go about disabling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/defaults-symbolichotkeys/ lists the key code for <kbd>F14</kbd> is `107`.

`defaults read com.apple.symbolichotkeys` outputs (note the `107` in `value.parameters`):

```
…
        53 =         {
            enabled = 0;
            value =             {
                parameters =                 (
                    65535,
                    107,
                    8388608
                );
                type = standard;
            };
        };
…
        55 =         {
            enabled = 1;
            value =             {
                parameters =                 (
                    65535,
                    107,
                    8912896
                );
                type = standard;
            };
        };
…
```

The mapping for `53` is already disabled (that's the one for "Decrease display brightness").

Running the following disables the <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F14</kbd> keyboard shortcut binding:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist AppleSymbolicHotKeys -dict-add 55 "<dict><key>enabled</key><false/></dict>"
```

If it doesn't take effect immediately, run the following:

```
$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u
```